# why is my third song not playing and how can I make it play?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am currently playing one song and after my first song ends the second song starts playing. When my second song ends the third song should start playing but it's not. How can I do this using the MediaPlayer.

This is my onCompletion code:

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    didFinishFirst = true;
    if(didFinishFirst) {

        Uri songUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.two);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), songUri);
        mp.start();
        mState = STATE_INITIALIZED;
        didFinishSecond = true;
    } else if(didFinishSecond){
        Uri songUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.three);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), songUri);
        mp.start();
        mState = STATE_INITIALIZED;
        didFinishThird = true;
    }
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // No need
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Because didFinishFirst is always true, so the first if branch is always taken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link the completion listener again to the new media player instance return by `MediaPLayer.create`. only then the `oncompletion` will be triggered

```
Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    didFinishFirst = true;
    if(didFinishFirst) {

        Uri songUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.two);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), songUri);
        mp.start();
        mState = STATE_INITIALIZED;
        didFinishSecond = true;
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    } else if(didFinishSecond){
        Uri songUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.three);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), songUri);
        mp.start();
        mState = STATE_INITIALIZED;
        didFinishThird = true;
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // No need
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It worked  . I also moved the didFinishFirst out of the onCompletion method. Thank you .

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

What I did here was start a MediaPlayer inside of a thread separate from the UI thread (In retrospect I should have just run my startMusic() code inside of an Async Task but I wrote this back when I was a novice programmer) 
I then set a listener for the end of each song and as soon as the first song ended according to the listener I started the next song and so on.

I hope this helps!.

```
  public static void startMusic(final Context context){
    handlerMusic = new Handler();
    handlerMusic.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            trackList.add(R.raw.diaz_choir);
            trackList.add(R.raw.diaz_strum_in_mouth);
            trackList.add(R.raw.diaz_underwater);
            trackList.add(R.raw.diaz_trap);

            for (int s = 0; s < trackList.size(); s++){
                newList.add(trackList.get(s));
            }

            mMediaPlayer =
                    MediaPlayer.create(context,newList.get(songNum));

            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mMediaPlayer.start();

            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(
                    new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    songNum++;
                       /*
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, newList.size() - 1);
                        mp.reset();

                        //mp.prepare();
                        mp.start();
                        */
                        mMediaPlayer =
                                MediaPlayer.create(
                                        context, newList.get(songNum));

                        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
                        mMediaPlayer.start();

                    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(
                            new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                    songNum++;
                     mMediaPlayer =
                             MediaPlayer.create(
                                     context, newList.get(songNum));

                                    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
                                    mMediaPlayer.start();

                                    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(
                                            new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                                    songNum++;
                                                    mMediaPlayer =
                                                            MediaPlayer.create(
                                                                    context, newList.get(songNum));

                                                    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                                    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
                                                    mMediaPlayer.start();

                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```